# Use HttpWebRequest with SharePoint Online and ADAL

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, c-sharp, adal

I have a C# desktop application which uses ADAL and the SharePoint Online CSOM to access SharePoint Online. The CSOM methods all work great, but sometimes I use a HttpWebRequest when I need to resolve a document ID URL to a file path (and I don't know which site or library the file is in). Even though I am setting the authorization header of the HttpWebRequest to the access token, the response's HTTP status is 401. **Any suggestions on how to fix this?**

I setup an AppRegistration in Azure as a native application with "Read and write items and lists in all site collections" permission. I didn't see any other applicable permissions that I would need to access the DocIdRedir.aspx page.

**Update:**
I am adding my ADAL token to a web request with the following properties:

> URL: /_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=F7YNH7UCH7KU-2102554853-455834
>   AllowAutoRedirect: False
>   KeepAlive: True
>   Method: HEAD
>   PreAuthenticate: True
>   Headers: Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxx

The response I get back is a 401 Unauthorized with a "WWW-Authenticate" header. When I use a cookie container instead, everything works great.

**So I am wondering if it is possible to use tokens with the DocIdRedir.aspx page?**

Comment: I've tried setting AllowAutoRedirect to True and Method to GET, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If the CSOM works great perhaps it would be an idea to retrieve the file info using CSOM search. Once you have the path you'll be able to spin up the proper clientcontext :-)

Comment: I tried that, but I was not able to get it to work. I used a QueryText set to the doc ID (e.g. "F7YNH7UCH7KU-2102554853-454904"), but the search never found any results.

Comment: That is strange, if the item is in the Search index. Does it show up in the search query tool, or like shown here https://richardstk.com/2014/12/12/search-by-document-id-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: No, it does not. These are test files that I recently copied to the document library. I'm wondering if the search crawler has not indexed them yet.

Comment: It should show up within 15 min, otherwise try to force a reload of the library using the reindex option under advanced settings. If that doesn't solve the index there is Michael Svensons reindex site collection script

Comment: It's been 40 minutes now and still does not show up. The doc ID URL from the file properties works when clicked, but the search still does not. If I search for the item ID ("454904"), I find the file, but I would prefer to use a search that is unique to the particular file I am looking for.

Comment: This article lists the different search properties:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/crawled-and-managed-properties-overview

DocID is not searchable, but is queryable. I'm not exactly sure what the difference is. So maybe you just can't search on doc ID.

My goal is to retrieve the file path for a given document ID URL. I have been searching for a way to do this and ended up using an HttpWebRequest and looking at the headers for the redirect URL. This was a workable solution for me, but doesn't work with ADAL for some reason.

Comment: I was able to get the KeywordQuery to work by using QueryText = "dlcDocIdOWSTEXT:xxxx". Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Update: The search service just isn't panning out for me. Recently added files aren't found by the search. I think I need to go back to my original plan of using a web request. This method worked for me before switching to using ADAL. I'm stumped why I am getting unauthorized exceptions.